# Checking nextScenes' movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have X scenes in flash as3 and I'm trying to disable a **"next button"**.
 When next scene doesn't have a certain movie clip. Let's say I wanna test whether testContent exists in the next scene called activityX. Any idea on this scenario ??

Comment: Come on @pramod.nikam.dev - this was the worst edit ever. Who's approving those?!

Comment: @AndreyPopov - Ohh is it? Please re edit it to make it more appropriate.

Comment: You've bolded something absolutely vague, and added synonym tag (which alone by itself is SO OLD that you cannot even imagine). Nice one. I can see you're doing 5-10 edits each day, most of them just like this one.. If you're doing it just for farming - get another hobby.

Answer (score -1):

Just test if it's on stage:

```
if (!this.getChildByName('nameofChild')) {
    // this clip is not present at the moment
}
```

Comment: I 'm pretty sure that this will test my current scene and not the next scene. Anyways I did it with just one extra variable maxActs. Checks if current scene number is >= maxActs so if I am on scene 7 and maxActs is 7 my button is disabled. Thanks alot though for the reply. Cheers!

Comment: I forgot to mention that every scene has a movie clip with the same name (testContent), so that wouldn't help me at all..